# Как правильно закэшировать в браузер Javascript/CSS файлы?

Tags: php, javascript, apache

**1.** Как правильно кэшировать  в браузер Javascript/CSS файлы, что бы при изменении версии файла, файл кэшировался.

**2.** И как правильно сделать версионность кэшируемых файлов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Кеширование осуществляется за счет заголовков ответа (`Cache-Control`). В apache кеширование можно включить используя `mod_expires` [Тут документация](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) 
   Так же может быть полезным для общего развития прочтение [данной статьи](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+Cache-control)
2. Часто используют добавление get параметра к имени файла. Например `/_build.css?v=1`. Второй подход - это складывать файл в папку с именем версии `/v1/_build.css`. Но первый вариант проще, т.к. он позволяет легче поддерживать прошлые версии (при публикации новой версии - старая останется доступна).

По просьбе из комментариев дополню первый пункт:
Т.к. мы управляем версиями наших файлов, то мы можем включить кеширование на максимальный срок (Хотя уверен, что хватит и месяца). 
Вот код для apache всё из той же статьи

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Т.е. для всех файлов с расширением css и js мы добавляем заголовок ответа, который говорит браузеру, что данные файлы необходимо закешировать на 2592000 секунд (30 дней)

Comment: Так в имени файлов запрещено ставить знак вопроса ' _build.css?v=1' Расскажите пожалуйста по подробнее, как указывать версию?

Comment: Почему запрешено? Даже если посмотреть код данного сайта, то там первыми строками идет `//cdn.sstatic.net/ru/img/favicon.ico?v=b95a7516ec95`

Comment: мы говорим про имея файла или про имя файла которое в URL? Тогда я ничего  не пойму. То есть мне нужно подменять заголовки запросов? как это делается?

Comment: Мы говорим про ссылки. Файл имеет обычное имя `_build.css` а вот ссылка на него имеет версию `_build.css?v=1`;

Comment: а как это сделать что бы менять ссылки именно на эти файлы?

Comment: 1. Вы должны включить кеширование нужных вам файлов (.css .js) в настройках сервера (читайте ссылки что я приложил в ответе). 2. Вы должны в вашу страницу (пускай это будет index.html) добавить версию к имени файлов. Как вы это будете делать - зависит от инструментов и технологий которыми вы пользуетесь.

Comment: Ага, понятно, Спасибо. Буду делать html+php, тогда уж. А как вы делаете?

Comment: Так стоп, я читал что у некоторых браузеров бывают проблемы , если у файла стоит вопросик.

Comment: У меня файлы кладутся в cdn в папочку с именем версии. Версия берется из changelog (специальный файл с историей изменений) и проставляется автоматически в нужные места во время финальной сборки.

Comment: Скорее всего эти браузеры уже вымерли/вымрут

Comment: А вы не могли бы описать как именно настроить , что вписать, что бы все работало. Я тут вижу только один более приемлемый вариант, это жесткое кэширование по времени, ну раз мы контролируем версии фалов. Можете пожалуйста описать, в ответе?

Comment: А можете показать как вы настроили свой файл .htaccess?

Comment: Я не использую .htaccess, т.к. у меня nginx + nodejs. Относительно кэширования, достаточно добавить в .htaccess следующие строки <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>  Дополнительно можете посмотреть эти статьи https://www.netangels.ru/support/hosting-howto/htaccess-cache/ и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498017/http-cache-headers-with-htaccess